# С чего начать создание подсветки синтаксиса ?

Tags: c#

Изначально хотел использовать готовые компоненты при работе. Присмотрел Scintilla для Net, но после установки компонента возникло множество ошибок при работе с этой библиотекой. Использовал VSExpress 2012. Если кто нибудь использовал данный компонент при работе расскажите как происходила установка.
Все это натолкнуло на создание своего компонента/библиотеки для подсветки.
Расскажите, каков принцип работы ? (использовать словари, регулярки и.т.д) Либо поделитесь ссылками на ресурсы где все это может быть описано в подробностях.

Comment: Имхо, с поиска существующих компонентов и парочки прототипов их использования.

Вот еще на в коллекцию:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30936/Using-ICSharpCode-TextEditor
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor

Если вы не ставите себе целью сделать редактор отдельным большим проектом, воспользуйтесь существующим решением.

Answer (score 1):

Одно время имел дело с библиотекой от Actipro.